# Why is this Bootstrap checkbox not working with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

When the input checkbox is checked, I want to append the `<div>` with a message. But somehow my code doesn't seem to work. Am I missing anything here?

Here's a link to what I've got so far - http://jsbin.com/petewadeho/edit?html,output

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <input id="inp" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" />

  <div id="out"></div>

  <script>
    $('#inp').click(function() {
      if (this.checked) {
        $("#out").append("hey");
      }
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have used Bootstrap, which is modifying the DOM structure of checkbox element. You need to use `.change()` event instead of `.click()`:

```
$('#inp').change(function(){
  if (this.checked) {
      $("#out").append("hey");
  }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/kenekekose/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1):

See the following code. here i used `onchange` function.

```
  <script>
    $('#inp').change(function(){
      if ($('#inp').prop( "checked" )) {
          $("#out").append("hey");
      }
    }); 
  </script>
```

Comment: Why repeat `$('#inp')` ? Use `$(this)` or `this`

Comment: Yes, we can use that too.sometimes for beginners, it have been a bit tricky to understand `$(this)`. that's why I directly used `$('#inp')`

Comment: I strongly suggest giving beginners best practices from the start

Answer (score 1):

The click listener you are setting is getting removed when Bootstrap modifies your checkbox.

The following code will add the listener to the body, so it won't get removed with the DOM element, while Bootstrap does its work

```
$('body').on('click', '#inp', function(){
  //do append
})
```